# Globally set AllowAutoRedirect in site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I know you can set the AllowAutoRedirect after you instantiate the web service but is there a way to do it in the applications config?  We are making lots of calls and was hoping there is a magic pill rather than acupuncture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this long gone post, because I'm currently dealing with it.

Not true, the reference to the WebService is actually a class that has a constructor where the AllowAutoRedirect can be manually set.

Look for Reference.cs inside your webservice folder under Web References folder.

In the constructor you want to write:

```
this.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
```

That way every time the web service is instantiated the property is set to true.

Answer (score 1):

Answering this as "No...there isn't".